# CUB (CUDA UnBound) equivalent of thrust::gather

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, thrust

Due to some performance issues with the Thrust libraries (see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192496/poor-performance-when-calling-cudamalloc-with-2-gpus-simultaneously) for more details), I am planning on re-factoring a CUDA application to use CUB instead of Thrust.  Specifically, to replace the thrust::sort_by_key and thrust::inclusive_scan calls).  In a particular point in my application I need to sort 3 arrays by key.  This is how I did this with thrust:

```
thrust::sort_by_key(key_iter, key_iter + numKeys, indices);
thrust::gather_wrapper(indices, indices + numKeys, 
      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(values1Ptr, values2Ptr, values3Ptr)),
      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(valuesOut1Ptr, valuesOut2Ptr, valuesOut3Ptr))
);
```

where

- `key iter` is a thrust::device_ptr that points to the keys i want to sort by
- `indices` point to a sequence (from 0 to numKeys-1) in device memory
- `values{1,2,3}Ptr` are device_ptrs to the values i want to sort
- `values{1,2,3}OutPtr` are device_ptrs to the sorted values

With the [CUB SortPairs](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html#ad42b50b38c4296c371572efdedd49fed) function I can sort a single value buffer, but not all 3 in one shot.  Problem is I don't see any CUB "gather-like" utilities.  Suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I suppose I could implement my own gather kernel, but is there any better way to do this other than:

```
template <typename Index, typename Value> 
__global__ void  gather_kernel(const unsigned int N, const Index * map, 
const Value * src, Value * dst) 
{ 
    unsigned int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 
    if (i < N) 
    { 
        dst[i] = src[map[i]]; 
    } 
}
```

The non-coalesed loads and stores make me chringe, but it probably unavoidable without a known structure on `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems what you want to achieve depends on `thrust::zip_iterator`. You could either

1. only replace `thrust::sort_by_key` by `cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs` and keep `thrust::gather`, or
2. zip `values{1,2,3}` into array of structures before using `cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs`

### update

After reading the implementation of `thrust::gather`,

```
$CUDA_HOME/include/thrust/system/detail/generic/gather.inl
```

you can see it is only a naive kernel like

```
__global__ gather(int* index, float* in, float* out, int len) {
  int i=...;
  if (i<len) { out[i] = in[index[i]]; }
}
```

Then I think your code above can be replaced by a single kernel without too much effort.

In this kernel, you could first use the CUB block-wize primitive [`cub::BlockRadixSort<...>::SortBlockedToStriped`](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_radix_sort.html#a9f707b1592f7354db0fba76a42afbc84) to get the sorted indices stored in registers and then perform a naive re-order copy as `thrust::gather` to fill `values{1,2,3}Out`.

Using `SortBlockedToStriped` rather than [`Sort`](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_radix_sort.html#aac3d9424388b0cb6da360624e627b61e) can do coalesced writing (not for reading though) when copying the `values`.

Comment: I was planning on keeping my thrust::gather calls for now, but eventually wanted to wean myself off thrust altogether.  I understand what you are getting at in your seconds suggestion, but wouldn't that cause poor memory coalescing performance when I go to access those sorted values (in a later CUDA kernel)?

Comment: Maybe you could unzip them after sorting... I append another suggestion in the answer.

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192496/poor-performance-when-calling-cudamalloc-with-2-gpus-simultaneously/19210828#19210828) for an explanation why I am moving away from thrust.

Comment: And by the way, if you look at the implementation of thrust, if the value type is greater than 8 bytes, thrust::sort_by_key does exactly what I have in my question:  creates a temporary sequence, sorts that sequence, and then uses it in a gather call.

Comment: Then keeping `thrust::gather` is a good choice, unless you also want to save the mem bandwidth for storing and loading `indices`.

Comment: PS: implementing `thrust::gather` with `zip_iterator` is quite easy, if you really don't want to see thrust. It's just a naive re-ordered copy, without shared mem and complex optimization.